# Issue on Targeting .prev() closest() Class of a Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjm63j56/) and let me know why I am not able to target the first  `.fa` class before the text box `#name` ?

I am trying this:

```
 $(this).prev().closest(".fa").addClass("err");
```

at this code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user err-test">Name</i>

                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-input-gray" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="btn-contact-rquest">Contact</button>
<br />
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
 $(function () {
 function txtInput(elem) {
     var inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
     if (inputData == "") {
         $(this).prev().closest(".fa").addClass("err");
     }
      else{
            return inputData;
        }
 }

     $("#btn-contact-rquest").on("click", function (e) {
         if (txtInput($('#name'))) {
              $("#result").html("No Error");
         } else {
             $("#result").html("Error");
         }

     });

 });
</script>
```

but cant target the `.fa` can you please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [.closest() docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/),For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree but in your case `.fa` is not ancestors of `$('#name')`.

Instead of

```
$(this).prev().closest(".fa").addClass("err");
```

Try

```
elem.prev().children(".fa").addClass("err");
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjm63j56/1/)

Comment: Thanks Kartikeya it is working but can you please let me know why did you change the this to elem?

Comment: You should use elem, it will make your life easier.  You could do it with this, but you'd need to modify your code.

Comment: $(this) will not work here.! exactly and can you please let me know why?

Comment: It has to do with scope.  Can you tell me what 'this' is refering to?

Comment: @Suffii..it will not work with `$(this)` because `$(this)` points to the current element but in your case you are calling `txtInput(elem)` from `btn-contact-rquest` click handler so in your case `$(this)` is not in the scope..

Comment: No it doesn't.  If you use it in the function, it would refer to the function itself.

Comment: Do you know how to pass variables in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fjm63j56/2/)

```
$(elem).parent().find(".fa:eq(0)").addClass("err");
```

Comment: there is no need of `$` with `elem` it is already a Jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss reading the html. 

Because before the input field, that is a div with class of input-group-addon. 
Hence, your selector is incorrect.

I changed your JS to :

```
 $(function () {
 function txtInput(elem) {
     var inputData = $(elem).val();
     if (inputData != "") {
         return inputData;
     }
      else{
         $(".input-group").addClass("err");
      }
 }

     $("#btn-contact-rquest").on("click", function (e) {
         if (txtInput($('#name'))) {
              $("#result").html("No Error");
         } else {
             $("#result").html("Error");
         }

     });

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fjm63j56/3/